# VBA Get Object's Methods

Tags: vba, object

Is there any way to get an object's methods and properties? What I have right now is:

```
set temp = GetObject("LDAP://" & distinguashedname)
msgbox temp.samaccountname
```

At this point I only know a few methods and properties of the objects I get using `GetObject`.

Comment: F2 and find/locate it in its library, assuming the object exists in a referenced library.

Comment: What if the object is not in a library?

Comment: Then how does the runtime know how to resolve the type and that is has a *samaccountname* property? Unless I'm missing something, if this code runs you should be able to find a *samaccountname* property somewhere in your project references. If the type of `temp` is `variant` you won't get intellisense for it. To know what the members are you need a ref. to the library that defines the type so you can work with an instance of it.

Comment: There might be a refrence to it, I am unsure. I'm quite new to VB. The end goal here is to have intellisense for all the objects that I deal with. As of right now I am just guessing what the names of the properties are. Mainly for LDAP objects, because I cannot find that much documentation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have moved on as this thread is old, but as someone who stumbled upon this while searching for and answer to the same question I figured I'd post an answer for the next person.

the reference you need to add is **Active DS Type Library** and if you are searching for user info the object type is ActiveDs.IADsUser.

```
dim temp as ActiveDs.IADsUser
```